# Jquery on click trigger two "events"

Tags: jquery, click

What I would like is very simple, but I am struggling with the syntax. When my element clicked, I would like my animate to be triggered and just after the .css(). Thank you in advance for your help. Cheers. Marc.

```
$('.content').click(function() {
    $('#contentWrapper').animate({
        "left": "-=475px"}, "fast"), 
    $(this).prev().css("display": "none");
});
```

Comment: Can you paste html here?

Comment: you DO know that `.css("display","none")` is the same as `.hide()` right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost. You need to pass the `complete` argument on [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) a function reference:

```
$('.content').click(function() {
    $('#contentWrapper').animate({
        "left": "-=475px"}, "fast", function () {
            $(this).prev().css("display", "none");
        }
    );
});
```

(Also, your syntax for [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css) was a bit off, you wanted `,` instead of `:`)

Comment: Since javascript has function scope, if you wrap the call inside another function `this` points to another object and not to the clicked object (at least that's what i think)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping out Andrew. Works great!

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: That's correct, `this` in the callback will reference the animated object.

Comment: Andrew, why it is , instead of :   I always use : for .css() and it works usually

Comment: @user1162116: You could also use `.css({ "display": "none" })`

Answer (score 2):

You should provide the second function as a callback

```
$('.content').click(function() {
    $('#contentWrapper').animate({
        "left": "-=475px"}, "fast", $(this).prev().css("display": "none"));
    });
});
```

EDIT - I think that in this way `this` points to the clicked element. If it's not yous should do

```
$('.content').click(function() {
    var that = this;
    $('#contentWrapper').animate({
        "left": "-=475px"}, "fast", $(that).prev().css("display": "none"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You supply the second part as a callback function, that means that it executes after the first function is complete. If you were acting on the **same** elemnt as the first animation then you could use **chaining** ('I'm not sure if you can use it in this circumstance because you didn't supply the html).

```
$('.content').click(function() {
    $('#contentWrapper').animate(
        {"left": "-=475px"},
        "fast",
        function(){
            $(this).prev().css("display": "none");
        }
    );
});
```